# Simple question on cauchy sequences and convergence

Tags: metric-spaces, field-theory, cauchy-sequences

Let $K$  be a field with metric defined on it.

$(x_n)$ be a cauchy sequence in  $K$ which does not converge to $0$.

Question is to see if we can  get a another cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ in $K$  such that $(x_ny_n)\rightarrow 1$.

I believe this happens but could not prove. Any hints are welcome.

We do not assume any topological completion. Everything we do has to be inside $K$.

Comment: How about $y_n = 1$ if $x_n=0$ and $y_n=x_n^{-1}$ (inverse for product of your field) if $x_n \neq 0$ ? (I let you do the proof that this is a Cauchy sequence, and that the limit is appropriate)

Comment: I dont think that gives cauchy sequence. @Vincent

Comment: $x_n$ cannot be equal to $0$ more than a finite number of times

Comment: That means you are saying $(x_n)$ is bounded below eventually by a positive number..

Comment: Yes, below or above, depending on the case.

Comment: Oh yes, then $\frac{1}{x_n}$ itself is cauchy,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Theorem*: If $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is Cauchy in a normed field $(K, | \cdot |)$ and $x_n \not\to 0$, then there exist $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\left( \frac 1 {x_n} \right)_{n \ge N}$ is Cauchy in $K$.

*Proof*: Since $x_n \not\to 0$ but $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, then there exist $r>0$ and $M \in \Bbb N$ such that $|x_n| \ge r$ for $n \ge M$ (otherwise, there would exist a subsequence tending to $0$ and, since the sequence is Cauchy, this would imply that the sequence itself tends to $0$, which would be a contradiction).

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy let $M' \in \Bbb N$ be such that $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon r^2$ for $m,n \ge M'$. Let $N = \max (M, M')$. Then

$$\left| \frac 1 {x_m} - \frac 1 {x_m} \right| = \frac {| x_n - x_m |} {|x_n| |x_m|} \le \frac {\epsilon r^2} {r^2} = \epsilon$$

whih shows that, indeed, $\left( \frac 1 {x_n} \right)_{n \ge N}$ is Cauchy in $K$.

Define now $y_n = \begin{cases} 0, & n < N \\ \frac 1 {x_n}, & n \ge N \end{cases}$. It follows that $(y_n)$ is Cauchy and $x_n y_n = 1$ for $n \ge N$, therefore, in particular, $x_n y_n \to 1$.

Comment: The above proof is for *normed* fields. It cannot be modified to work for *metric* fields because it uses in an essential way that $|x_n y_n| = |x_n| |y_n|$. In fact, I do not even know whether the claim is true for arbitrary metrics that are not necessarily compatible with the underlying algebraic structure. I believe it is not, but I do not have an example at hand.

Comment: I am interested in normed fields and this suits for my purpose...

Comment: Suppose given $\epsilon>0$ and $M\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\geq M$ such that $|x_n|<\epsilon$. As $(x_n)$ is cauchy, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $L\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m\geq L$. In particular, for this $L$ there exists $n\geq L$ such that $|x_n|<\epsilon$. For this $n$, we have $|x_m|\leq |x_m-x_n|+|x_n|<2\epsilon$ which imply that $(x_m)\rightarrow 0$, a contradiction. So, there exists $r>0$ and $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n|\geq r$ for all $n\geq M$.... I do not see necessity of subsequence convergence and using cauchy property one more time.